# Create subsets of time series from one data frame in order to run SeasonalMannKendall trend tests by station

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I have the following data with about 13 different stations:

```
> dput(RawData[1:10,])
structure(list(Station = c(469, 469, 469, 469, 469, 469, 469, 
469, 469, 469), Classification = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("  Approved  ", "  Conditionally Approved  ", 
"  Prohibited  "), class = "factor"), SampleDate = structure(c(8504, 
8504, 8505, 8505, 8532, 8532, 8533, 8533, 8561, 8561), class = "Date"), 
Year = c(1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 
1993, 1993), SWTemp = c(10, 11, 10, 10, 14, 15, 12, 14, 15, 
16), Salinity = c(26, 28, 28, 30, NA, NA, 30, 30, 28, 18), 
FecalColiform = c(1.8, 2, 2, 1.8, 2, 2, 1.8, 1.8, 4.5, 2)), .Names = c("Station", 
"Classification", "SampleDate", "Year", "SWTemp", "Salinity", 
"FecalColiform"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to run a SeasonalMannKendal on the fecal coliform data for each station separately.  I know it has to be a time series.  How do I make each station into it's own time series so that I can run these tests?

I have tried to reshape the data to list station results by sample date, but this creates NAs for certain dates and I can't run the test that way either.

What would my best approach be?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a few ways, but this way will give you a list of dataframes, where each dataframe has the data for only one Station. I also added in `as.ts` to convert the data into a time series using the TSA library. You might need to play with the dates to get them how you want them.

```
library("TSA")
mylist = list()
for(i in 1:unique(RawData$Station)){
  mylist[[i]] = as.ts(RawData[RawData$Station == i,])
}

names(mylist) = unique(RawData$Station)
```

Now you'll be able to pick which site you want by doing something like `mylist[["429"]]`.

If you just want separate dataframes that aren't in a list, you'd do something like:

```
Station1 = RawData[RawData$Station == 1,]
Station2 = RawData[RawData$Station == 2,]
```

...etc.

PS, in the future it would be helpful to use `dput(yourdata)` so that someone can easily copy-paste your problem and work on it. Thanks for giving a clear example though!

Comment: Thank you Nancy! I have included the dput above.  Your second suggestion works very well.  I tried running the first set of code and I'm getting the same error I have seen before.  In this format there are no holes in the Fecal Coliform column that I'm interested in.   Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations In addition: Warning message:
In 1:unique(RawData$Station) :
  numerical expression has 13 elements: only the first used

Comment: Roger, let me take a look.